# Oozie - FileSystem maprfs Does Not Exist

Tags: oozie, mapr

I am running a virtual cluster running MapR 4.1.0 and Yarn.  When I try to launch a job via Oozie, I get the error:

```
[user01@mapr1node no-op]$ oozie job -config job.properties -run
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/mapr/oozie/oozie-4.1.0/lib/slf4j-simple-1.6.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/mapr/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
Error: E0902 : E0902: Exception occured: [No FileSystem for scheme: maprfs]
```

Below is my modified job.properties file (I had to change the Jobtracker to reference yarn).

```
nameNode=maprfs:///
jobTracker=mapr1node:8032
queueName=default
examplesRoot=examples

oozie.wf.application.path=maprfs:/user/${user.name}/${examplesRoot}/apps/no-op
```

I have spent a few days trying to figure out why maprfs is not recognized (I can confirm this same example works for others).  I suspect something is misconfigured in my cluster but I cannot figure out what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a known issue in maprfs around Ooozie.  Below is a link where a MAPR engineer describes a workaround.

https://community.mapr.com/thread/9539

It worked for most (but not all) of those who did it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes these steps are working.
https://community.mapr.com/thread/9539#comment-34807

And install the latest patch to cluster using below command
1057  service mapr-warden stop
 1058  service mapr-zookeeper stop

vi /etc/yum.repos.d/maprtech.repo
Add the patch baseurl to repo file.
" baseurl=http://package.mapr.com/patches/releases/v4.1.0/redhat/   "
then

1064  yum install mapr-patch -y
 1065  service mapr-zookeeper start
 1066  service mapr-warden start
 1067  maprcli node cldbmaster
 1068  service mapr-warden qstatus
 1069  service mapr-zookeeper qstatus
 1070  maprcli node cldbmaster
 1071  maprcli node list -columns svc
 1072  netstat -plant| grep 11000
  bin/oozie-start.sh

then SUbmit the sample job
[mapr@VM205 oozie-4.1.0]$ bin/oozie job -oozie http://10.10.72.205:11000/oozie -config examples/apps/pig/job.properties  -run

Things ll work fine.